# Error when loading YOLOv5 with C++ and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, yolov5

I am trying to run object detection using YOLOv5 with C++ and Opencv's dnn. I mainly followed this example: https://github.com/doleron/yolov5-opencv-cpp-python/blob/main/cpp/yolo.cpp

my code ended up being :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
void load_net(cv::dnn::Net& net, bool is_cuda)
{
    auto result = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX("yolov5s.onnx");
    if (is_cuda)
    {
        std::cout << "Attempty to use CUDA\n";
        result.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
        result.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Running on CPU\n";
        result.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
        result.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);
    }
    net = result;
}
const std::vector<cv::Scalar> colors = { cv::Scalar(255, 255, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0) };
const float INPUT_WIDTH = 640.0;
const float INPUT_HEIGHT = 640.0;
const float SCORE_THRESHOLD = 0.2;
const float NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.4;
const float CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.4;
struct Detection
{
    int class_id;
    float confidence;
    cv::Rect box;
};
cv::Mat format_yolov5(const cv::Mat& source) {
    int col = source.cols;
    int row = source.rows;
    int _max = MAX(col, row);
    cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(_max, _max, CV_8UC3);
    source.copyTo(result(cv::Rect(0, 0, col, row)));
    return result;
}
void detect(cv::Mat& image, cv::dnn::Net& net, std::vector<Detection>& output, const std::vector<std::string>& className) {
    cv::Mat blob;
    auto input_image = format_yolov5(image);
    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(input_image, blob, 1. / 255., cv::Size(INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT), cv::Scalar(), true, false);
    net.setInput(blob);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> outputs;
    net.forward(outputs, net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames());
    float x_factor = input_image.cols / INPUT_WIDTH;
    float y_factor = input_image.rows / INPUT_HEIGHT;
    float* data = (float*)outputs[0].data;
    const int dimensions = 85;
    const int rows = 25200;
    std::vector<int> class_ids;
    std::vector<float> confidences;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> boxes;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        float confidence = data[4];
        if (confidence >= CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD) {
            float* classes_scores = data + 5;
            cv::Mat scores(1, className.size(), CV_32FC1, classes_scores);
            cv::Point class_id;
            double max_class_score;
            minMaxLoc(scores, 0, &max_class_score, 0, &class_id);
            if (max_class_score > SCORE_THRESHOLD) {
                confidences.push_back(confidence);
                class_ids.push_back(class_id.x);
                float x = data[0];
                float y = data[1];
                float w = data[2];
                float h = data[3];
                int left = int((x - 0.5 * w) * x_factor);
                int top = int((y - 0.5 * h) * y_factor);
                int width = int(w * x_factor);
                int height = int(h * y_factor);
                boxes.push_back(cv::Rect(left, top, width, height));
            }
        }
        data += 85;
    }
    std::vector<int> nms_result;
    cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, SCORE_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD, nms_result);
    for (int i = 0; i < nms_result.size(); i++) {
        int idx = nms_result[i];
        Detection result;
        result.class_id = class_ids[idx];
        result.confidence = confidences[idx];
        result.box = boxes[idx];
        output.push_back(result);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::string> class_list = { "person", "bicycle", "car", "motorbike", "aeroplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat", "traffic light", "fire hydrant", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack", "umbrella", "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis", "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat", "baseball glove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle", "wine glass", "cup", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli", "carrot", "hot dog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "sofa", "pottedplant", "bed", "diningtable", "toilet", "tvmonitor", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard", "cell phone", "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator", "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors", "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush" };
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    if (!capture.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening video file\n";
        return -1;
    }
    bool is_cuda = argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "cuda") == 0;
    cv::dnn::Net net;
    load_net(net, is_cuda);
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int frame_count = 0;
    float fps = -1;
    int total_frames = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        capture.read(frame);
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "End of stream\n";
            break;
        }
        std::vector<Detection> output;
        detect(frame, net, output, class_list);
        frame_count++;
        total_frames++;
        int detections = output.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < detections; ++i)
        {
            auto detection = output[i];
            auto box = detection.box;
            auto classId = detection.class_id;
            const auto color = colors[classId % colors.size()];
            cv::rectangle(frame, box, color, 3);
            cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 20), cv::Point(box.x + box.width, box.y), color, cv::FILLED);
            cv::putText(frame, class_list[classId].c_str(), cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 5), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        }
        if (frame_count >= 30)
        {
            auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            fps = frame_count * 1000.0 / std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
            frame_count = 0;
            start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
        if (fps > 0)
        {
            std::ostringstream fps_label;
            fps_label << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
            fps_label << "FPS: " << fps;
            std::string fps_label_str = fps_label.str();
            cv::putText(frame, fps_label_str.c_str(), cv::Point(10, 25), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        }
        cv::imshow("output", frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(1) != -1)
        {
            capture.release();
            std::cout << "finished by user\n";
            break;
        }
        char c = (char)cv::waitKey(25);//Allowing 25 milliseconds frame processing time and initiating break condition//
        if (c == 27) { //If 'Esc' is entered break the loop//
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Total frames: " << total_frames << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get an error when reading the onnx file and this is the console's output

```
OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Unspecified error (> Node [Range@ai.onnx]:(354) parse error: OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:621: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "354" of type "Range" in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::LayerData::getLayerInstance'
> ) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::ONNXImporter::handleNode, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp, line 928
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Unspecified error (> Node [Range@ai.onnx]:(354) parse error: OpenCV(4.5.5) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:621: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "354" of type "Range" in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::LayerData::getLayerInstance'
> ) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::ONNXImporter::handleNode, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp, line 928
```

Does anyone know what is the problem here and how to fix it?

Edit: if you want to run it and check the output for yourselves you can download the model from https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases

Comment: what exactly did you download from ultralytics ? if you had to convert it to onnx, how so ?

Comment: You can download onnx files directly I think. I downloaded both yolov5n.onnx and yolov5s.onnx (They are in the list of assets).

Comment: check this https://github.com/HefnySco/yolov5-opencv-dnn-cpp the code is working also onnx model is uploaded and you can try it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to share my experience.

- Windows 10, x64
- GeForce 1660 Ti
- Visual Studio 2019, version 16
- OpenCV 4.6.0
- Python 3.8
- CUDA 11.6, cuDNN 8.4
- PyTorch 1.12.0+cu116

1. Download and build OpenCV source.

> Follow the following guideline:
>
> https://machinelearningprojects.net/build-opencv-with-cuda-and-cudnn/
>
> In my case, I additionally make the following items unchecked since I
> need only python and C++: test, objc, java, js

2. Git clone and run export.py to get the onnx model and detect.py to check the OpenCV dnn module.

Commands:

```
python export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --simplify --include onnx
python detect.py --weights yolov5s.onnx --device 0 --dnn
```

> Don't forget to add parameter --simplify, or you will fail when you
> load it on Visual Studio using OpenCV and C++. Second command is for
> checking OpenCV dnn module, in case of failing here, it will be also
> failed on Visual Studio.

3. cuDNN installation
   https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html
4. Code implementation

- Check backend and target

The following code snippet would be used to do it.

```
const string namesBackend[] = {
    "DNN_BACKEND_DEFAULT",
    "DNN_BACKEND_HALIDE",
    "DNN_BACKEND_INFERENCE_ENGINE",
    "DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV",
    "DNN_BACKEND_VKCOM",
    "DNN_BACKEND_CUDA",
    "DNN_BACKEND_WEBNN",
    "DNN_BACKEND_TIMVX"
};
const string namesTarget[] = {
    "DNN_TARGET_CPU",
    "DNN_TARGET_OPENCL",
    "DNN_TARGET_OPENCL_FP16",
    "DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD",
    "DNN_TARGET_VULKAN",
    "DNN_TARGET_FPGA",
    "DNN_TARGET_CUDA",
    "DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16",
    "DNN_TARGET_HDDL",
    "DNN_TARGET_NPU"
};
// list dnn backends
auto listBackend = cv::dnn::getAvailableBackends();
cout << "########## Avaliable Backends ##########" << endl;
for (const auto& bkend : listBackend) {
   cout << "Backend: " << namesBackend[bkend.first] << ", Target: " << 
   namesTarget[bkend.second] << endl;
}
int numDevices = cv::cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
cout << "Number of cuda device: " << numDevices << endl;
```

- Load Model

Code snippet:

```
const string model_path_yolov5s = "d:\\C++\\PedestrianDetector\\models\\yolov5s.onnx";
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(model_path_yolov5s);
net.setPreferableBackend(cv::dnn::DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
net.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16);
```

- Detect

Code snippet:

```
chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = chrono::system_clock::now();
cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, blob, 1.0 / 255.0, cv::Size(INPUT_WIDTH, 
INPUT_HEIGHT), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), true, false);
net.setInput(blob);
vector<cv::Mat> detections;
vector<string> outLayerNames = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
net.forward(detections, outLayerNames);
chrono::system_clock::time_point endTime = chrono::system_clock::now();
chrono::milliseconds millSec = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

once again :)

Maybe my `Python` code will help you

```py
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX("best.onnx")

frame = cv2.imread(f'img.png')
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,640)) #IMAGE SIZE

MEAN = 255 * np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
STD = 255 * np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
x = np.array(frame)
x = x.transpose(-1, 0, 1)
x = (x - MEAN[:, None, None]) / STD[:, None, None]
x = x.reshape(1,3,640,640)

net.setInput()

preds = net.forward()
```

or my `Go` code will help you

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "math"
    "sync"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {

    net := NewYoloModelCls("best.onnx")

    frame := gocv.IMRead("3_resize.png", gocv.IMReadColor)
    defer frame.Close()

    gocv.Resize(frame, &frame, image.Point{640, 640}, 0, 0, gocv.InterpolationLinear)

    result, err := net.Invoke(&frame)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer net.Close()

    fmt.Println(result)

}

type YoloModelCls struct {
    net   *gocv.Net
    mutex sync.Mutex
}

func NewYoloModelCls(model_path string) YoloModelCls {
    net := gocv.ReadNetFromONNX(model_path)

    net.SetPreferableBackend(gocv.NetBackendOpenCV)
    net.SetPreferableTarget(gocv.NetTargetCPU)

    return YoloModelCls{
        net: &net,
    }
}

func (model *YoloModelCls) Invoke(frame *gocv.Mat) (float64, error) {
    model.mutex.Lock()
    defer model.mutex.Unlock()

    blob := gocv.BlobFromImage(*frame, 1, image.Pt(frame.Rows(), frame.Cols()), gocv.NewScalar(0, 0, 0, 0), true, false)
    defer blob.Close()

    err := normalize(&blob)
    if err != nil {
        return 0.0, err
    }

    model.net.SetInput(blob, "")

    preds := model.net.Forward("")
    defer preds.Close()

    normal_preds, err := preds.DataPtrFloat32()
    if err != nil {
        return 0.0, err
    }
    result := softmax(normal_preds)

    return result[0], nil
}

func (model *YoloModelCls) Close() {
    model.net.Close()
}

func normalize(blob *gocv.Mat) error {
    // this will return the matrix (1*3*640*640 ) as an array (1228800)
    arr_matrix, err := blob.DataPtrFloat32()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    x := blob.Size()[2]
    y := blob.Size()[3]

    mean := [3]float32{123.675, 116.28, 103.53}
    std := [3]float32{58.395, 57.12, 57.375}

    //normalize the red channel
    for i := 0; i < x*y; i++ {
        arr_matrix[i] = (arr_matrix[i] - mean[0]) / std[0]
    }

    //normalize the green channel
    for i := x * y; i < x*y*2; i++ {
        arr_matrix[i] = (arr_matrix[i] - mean[1]) / std[1]
    }

    //normalize the blue channel
    for i := x * y * 2; i < x*y*3; i++ {
        arr_matrix[i] = (arr_matrix[i] - mean[2]) / std[2]
    }

    return nil
}

//softmax by 2 classes
func softmax(preds []float32) [2]float64 {
    exp_preds := [2]float64{}
    exp_preds[0] = math.Exp(float64(preds[0]))
    exp_preds[1] = math.Exp(float64(preds[1]))

    sum := exp_preds[0] + exp_preds[1]

    exp_preds[0] /= sum
    exp_preds[1] /= sum

    return exp_preds
}
```

[It helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617755/how-to-replicate-pytorch-normalization-in-opencv-or-numpy/69630766#69630766)

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the function readNet to load the onnx file instead of readNetFromONNX. I also used ultrlytics Yolo V5 repo to export the (.pt) file to (.onnx) file. In place of this auto result = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX("yolov5s.onnx"); you need to use
auto net = cv::dnn::readNet("D:/yolov5-master/yolov5-master/yolov5n.onnx");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).